# Read CosmosDb items from pyspark (Databricks) with an inconsistent model

Tags: pyspark, azure-cosmosdb, azure-databricks

Let's say I have two items in CosmosDb:

```
{
  "Test": {
    "InconsistentA": 10
  },
  "Common": 1
}
```

```
{
  "Test": {
    "InconsistentB": 10
  },
  "Common": 2
}
```

How to read this data so to have the following schema:

- Test: string (the JSON string of the inconsistent part of the model)
- Common: int (the consistent part of the model)

I don't know in advance what the model is and the spark CosmosDb driver (com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark) only reads X first items in CosmosDb to infer the schema.

What I have tried is enforcing the schema this way:

```
|-- Test: string (nullable = true)
|-- Common: integer (nullable = true)
```

But the result of the Test column is:

```
'{ InconsistentA=10 }'
```

Instead of:

```
'{ "InconsistentA": 10 }'
```

Comment: You can write a custom SQL Query to fetch the data, and that custom query (`spark.cosmos.read.customQuery`) will be used to infer the schema: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos-spark_3_2-12/docs/configuration-reference.md#query-config. You probably want to make the Test property a projection of the inner value to flatten it.

Comment: I'm actually already using a customQuery. Btw I'm using Apache Spark 2.4.5